# Writing the Resolvent as an Integral

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory

Let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space, and let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ not in the spectrum of $A$, i.e. the resolvent operator $(A - z)^{-1}$ is well-defined (bounded, etc). I want to justify the identity
$$ (A - z)^{-1} = i \int_0^\infty e^{-i(A- z)s} ds$$
My thinking is the following. I would like to formally show that $$ i (A- z) \int_0^\infty e^{-i(A- z)s} ds = 1 $$
the identity operator. It seems like simple change of variables but I'm not sure exactly how to carry this out. It looks like, letting $u = e^{-i(A- z)s}$ that the integral should just turn out to be $\int_0^1 du$ and hence equal to 1. I would appreciate any hints/help! Thanks.

Comment: This older question seems relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2989175/137524

Comment: Do you know the spectral theorem?

Comment: I do know the spectral theorem, in the form $$ A = \int_{\sigma(A)} \lambda dP_\lambda$$. Would this help? The older link is very relevant, also this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824696/is-this-a-general-identity-for-the-resolvent-solved-integral-representation-o?rq=1. Thank you!